# Adjust the sidebar size of Touchfolio theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using, [Touchfolio](http://dimsemenov.com/themes/touchfolio/) WordPress theme.

I need to adjust the size of the sidebar so that the social media plugin (Facebook) will fit. Now it's popping out from sidebar.

This is the best and smallest size from Facebook.

I am unable to figure out where I can change the size of the sidebar.

I have attached screenshot below.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: You want to increase the sidebar size or decrease the social box size ?

Comment: increase the sidebar size. is that possible?

Comment: offcource possible, try increasing size of .main-header something like .main-header { width: 400px;  } if not worked use .main-header { width: 400px !important;  }

Comment: It works. thank you so much.

Comment: mark it as helpful and adding an answer mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code .    `.main-header { width: 400px; } if not worked use .main-header { width: 400px !important; }`